# ".eth() method not found" when returning Http struct in a function

Tags: http, rust

I want to establish an http connection to a Ganache test blockchain.
Going through the GitHub page of the web3 crate I found this example:

```
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> web3::Result<()> {
    let _ = env_logger::try_init();
    let transport = web3::transports::Http::new("http://localhost:7545")?;
    let web3 = web3::Web3::new(transport);

    let mut accounts = web3.eth().accounts().await?;

    ...

    Ok(())
}
```

However I want to implement the connection setup in a function. So I tried the following:

```
async fn establish_web3_connection_http(url: &str) -> web3::Result<Web3<Http>>{
    let transport = web3::transports::Http::new(url)?;
    Ok(web3::Web3::new(transport))
}

...

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> web3::Result<()> {
    let web3_con = establish_web3_connection_http("http://localhost:7545");

    println!("Calling accounts.");
    let mut accounts = web3_con.eth().accounts().await?;
    
    Ok(())
}
```

This results in the following error:

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQ14v.png)

I am not sure why I do not return the correct value. There is not error when I
don't call web3_con, so the function seems to be fine.

Is the return value somehow wrong, or how I call it?

Comment: Please paste your error message into your question. Adding images of text is discouraged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`establish_web3_connection_http()` is an async function, so it returns a future. You're trying to call `.eth()` on the future, when you probably want to call it on the value produced by the future.  You need to await the result of this function:

```
let web3_con = establish_web3_connection_http("http://localhost:7545").await?;
//                                                                    ^^^^^^^
```

However, you don't do any awaiting in `establish_web3_connection_http()`, so there's no reason it needs to be async in the first place.  You could just remove `async` from its signature instead:

```
fn establish_web3_connection_http(url: &str) -> web3::Result<Web3<Http>>{
```